# Raster image changes colour after import

Tags: qgis, raster, ubuntu, image

after raster .tiff image import in project, it changes colour.

Imported

[image]

Original

[image]

What could be the options in QGIS 2.18.16 to get back to original colours? 
This kind of problem is quite new, appeard in this week:)

Comment: Check the Band rendering settings from the Layer - Properties - Style. Play with band order. Is it possible that you have received 4-band images with RGB and near infrared bands?

Comment: This happens with old images I have already worked with. Have played with Style options, no results yet. After few options image dissapears at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, guys.

Fixed to original.

[image]

Playing with colour bands. Its working today.

It seems, I have changed something in Render options, accidentally. Should be as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by user30184, I made similar effect by:

- Red band = Band 1 (Red)
- Green band = Band 1 (Red)
- Blue band = Band 2 (Green)

And setting contrast enhancement to `Stretch to MinMax`.

[image]